# Creation of multiple rulers using wx python rulercntl

Tags: wxpython

I need to write a gui that contains multiple rulers permitting users to select starting and ending values that will be passed to later code. The wx.lib.rulercntl seems to have everything I need. I'm new to wxpython and don't know how to go about doing this. Has anyone done something similar? I've found some documentation on rulercntl, but don't comprehend it.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example which sets up a RulerCtrl with two indicators, and reports the new position when one of them is moved.

```
import wx, wx.lib.agw.rulerctrl as rc

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.ruler = rc.RulerCtrl(self, orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.ruler.AddIndicator(id=100, value=0.0)
        self.ruler.AddIndicator(id=101, value=6.5)
        self.text  = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.ruler.Bind(rc.EVT_INDICATOR_CHANGED, self.onIndicator)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.ruler, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.text,  1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.SetMinSize((400,300))

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Show()

    def onIndicator(self, evt):
        ind_id = evt.GetId()
        ind_pos= evt.GetValue()
        self.text.AppendText('Indicator %s: %s\n' % (ind_id,ind_pos))
        evt.Skip()

app = wx.App(False) 
frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "RulerCtrl") 
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: that's really helpful! Is there a way to add multiple rulers to the window?

Comment: Sure, you can add any number of them to the window the same way the first one was added.  If you're not already familiar with sizers, you'll probably want to learn about wx.BoxSizer or wx.GridBagSizer depending on what kind of layout you're going for.